# Azure Cosmos DB, should have read access to Cosmos DB but the read keys should not be visible

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb, rbac

This below defined roles shows the keys section and the read keys are visible. What changes has to be done above role so that there is read permission to Cosmos DB account but keys should not be visible

using this role permission

```
{
  "Name": "CosmosDbtest1",
  "Id": "a1b2c3d4",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "To test the read access for keys",
  "Actions": [
    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/read",
    "Microsoft.DocumentDB/*/read",
    "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readonlykeys/action",
    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
    
  ],
  "NotActions": 
  [
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/listKeys/action",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readonlykeys/read"
  ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/"1234"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the below steps to restrict key access on **Azure Cosmos DB**.

I have created a custom role as below.

[image]

**Restrict Permission:**

[image]

**JSON :**

```
{
    "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/fbdf93bf-df7d-xxxx-xxxx-9458aa1360c8",
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "Cosmos DB Account Reader Role",
        "description": "Can read Azure Cosmos DB Accounts data",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/read",
                    "Microsoft.DocumentDB/*/read",
                   
                    "Microsoft.Insights/MetricDefinitions/read",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/Metrics/read",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
                    "Microsoft.Support/*"
                ],
                "notActions": [
                 "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readonlykeys/action",
                ],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Once create the custom role, assign the same roles to the user as below.

**Open Azure Cosmos DB > Access control (IAM) > add > Add role assignment .**

[image]

**User Assignment:**

[image]

If I tried to log in with the same user, getting the below result.

[image]

Comment: This also block the data explorer ,cannot view database,collections or docs as well

Comment: @techzouk the data explorer on Azure Portal uses the access keys as credentials. So there's no way to enable the data explorer without exposing the access keys.